# math functions c# in unity

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine

I trying to have `ShareScreenshotWithText()` called every time a float from a different script, `settings.screenshotintervals`, is called. Right now my code is

```
(scoreTeam1 + scoreTeam2 == settings.screenshotintervals * (1) | scoreTeam1 + scoreTeam2 == settings.screenshotintervals * 2 | scoreTeam1 + scoreTeam2 == settings.screenshotintervals * 3 | scoreTeam1 + scoreTeam2 == settings.screenshotintervals * 4
```

Is their any easier way to do this other then typing this out but changing the number every time? The other script has a slider that the person can change the value of.

Comment: The bitwise OR there looks really suspicous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can produce range of numbers and check whether any of these numbers multiplied by intervals gives you sum of scores:

```
Enumerable.Range(1,4).Any(i => settings.screenshotintervals * i == scoreTeam1 + scoreTeam2)
```

Sorry, I missed that values are floats. As @Everts has stated - the best solution here will be [Mathf.Approximately](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) usage for values comparison:

```
var totalScore = scoreTeam1 + scoreTeam2;
var result = Enumerable.Range(1,4)
       .Any(i =>  Mathf.Approximately(settings.screenshotintervals * i, totalScore));
```

Comment: if those are floats, it is really unlikely the equality will ever happen (floating inaccuracy). Using Mathf.Approximately would help.